# 特定のmodelでModuleをincludeしないようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### 概要

ApplicationRecordでHogeModuleをincludeするようになっていて、
ApplicationRecordを継承するとModuleがincludeされてしまう。

PiyoClassではincludeしたくない場合にどのように実現すべきかの助言を頂きたいです。

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HogeModule
end
```

```rb
class PiyoClass < ApplicationRecord
  # このクラスではHogeModuleをincludeしたくない
end
```

### 試したこと

「`method_missing': undefined method`include_class?'」となってしまう

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HogeModule if include_class?

  def include_class?
    true
  end
end
```

```rb
class PiyoClass < ApplicationRecord
  # このクラスではHogeModuleをincludeしたくない
  def include_class?
    false
  end
end
```

### 条件

以下の条件を満たしたいです

- ApplicationRecordを継承すること
- includeしない場合にモデルに何かしら記述する

### 環境

- Rails5.2

Answer (score 1):

自分の知る限り、一度 include した module を uninclude することはできない気がしているので、

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class HogeApplicationRecord < ApplicationRecord
  include HogeModule

  self.abstract_class = true
end

class PiyoClass < ApplicationRecord
end

# それ以外のクラスは HogeApplicationRecord を継承する
```

とするのが、妥当な解答かなと思っています。

Answer (score 0):

一つの技法として、`Class#inherited`を活用する方法があります。

```rb
module MyMudule
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

class Parent
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.include MyMudule if subclass.name == 'Child1'
  end
end

class Child1 < Parent
end

class Child2 < Parent
end

child1 = Child1.new
puts child1.respond_to?(:hello) # => true
child2 = Child2.new
puts child2.respond_to?(:hello) # => false
```

このように、特定の名前の子クラスのみで`include`を行ったり、逆に`include`を行わなかったりできます。
この方法の欠点としては親クラスが「どのクラスがモジュールを継承するか（またはしないか）」の知識を持たなくてはならないことです。単に親クラスを2つに分ける方法と比較するとこちらのほうが可読性には劣ります。